# How to authenticate access to an external hard drive?

Tags: external-hdd

I have an external hard drive. I would like to restrict access to it only by me. How can I do that?

Although I only use Ubuntu when I connect to the external hard drive, I also would like it to be protected when connected to other operating systems if someone one else that is not authorized has it.

Thanks.

Comment: Search for "Encrypted Disk" if you want the whole disk to look like noise to other OSs, search for "Encrypted Directory" if it's OK if other OSs can see the free space.